# Manipulating Client Files in Office Add-Ins

Tags: visual-studio, office365, add-in, office-js

I am developing an Office Add-in using Visual Studio.  However, I want to rename some files, delete others, and upload a file.  Visual studio allows me to use HTML and JavaScript.  However, neither of these allows me to access or manipulate the files on the client PC.

I could do this easily in the old VBA add-in development methodology, but I am new to the new "progressive web App" technique.  I would appreciate an suggestions about how to access and manipulate client files in an Office Add-In developed with Visual Studio.

Thank You.

Comment: This sort of addins runs both on the client computer and in the web (when you open file in the office online , or dropbox for example) in the second case, this can be done on any computer. Therefore there are no local files

Comment: In addition to what @Nikolay said, It would be a madness if any web-accessed files could modify your local files. So you have to decide. If you really need to access those files, you should use VSTO add-ins. Those, however, won't be accessible on all of your devices and on outlook online.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the local file system (except for cookies) from an Office Web Add-in for the same reason that you cannot from a web application. It would be a security risk.